# PGFPLOTS Graph with many x values for the same y label

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create a diagram with PGFPLOTS like [this](http://www.eso.org/public/archives/images/large/eso0842c.jpg):

[image]

This is my data file:

```
SN  STAR    PLANET  R   RU  RL
1   51 Peg  b   0.0521068   0.000868447 0.000868447
2   55 Cnc  b   0.113377    0.00188961  0.00188961
2   55 Cnc  c   0.237305    0.00395515  0.00395515
2   55 Cnc  d   5.47467 0.0939312   0.0939312
2   55 Cnc  e   0.0154393   0.000257321 0.000257321
2   55 Cnc  f   0.773567    0.0129169   0.0129169
3   6 Lyn   b   2.18639 0.055765    0.055765
4   61 Vir  b   0.05006 0.000834347 0.000834347
4   61 Vir  c   0.216926    0.00361774  0.00361774
4   61 Vir  d   0.474527    0.00803427  0.00803427
5   7 CMa   b   1.80264 0.0641495   0.0641495
6   70 Vir  b   0.483601    0.00806003  0.00806003
7   75 Cet  b   1.97678 0.0555905   0.0555905
8   81 Cet  b   2.28088 0.0928283   0.0928283
```

This is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title=Fig. 1: Exoplanets data and model prediction, 
    xmode=log, xlabel={Semi-major axis (AU)},
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{PLANET} \as \labelplanet},
    nodes near coords={\labelplanet},
    flexible yticklabels from table={Exoplanets/test.dat}{STAR}{col sep=tab}, ytick=data, y dir=reverse,
]
\addplot+[mark=*, only marks, mark size=0.33, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] 
table[x=R,x error plus=RU,x error minus=RL,y=SN,col sep=tab] {Exoplanets/test.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that instead of labeling line #2 with *55 Cnc* and line #3 with *6 Lyn*, I get 5 lines (#2-#6) labeled *55 Cnc*.

Obviously, the error is in an incompatibilty with the code I copied from another post to create the labels:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=tab]{Exoplanets/test.dat}\datatable
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/flexible yticklabels from table/.code n args={3}{%
        \pgfplotstableread[#3]{#1}\coordinate@table
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumn{#2}\of{\coordinate@table}\to\pgfplots@yticklabels
        \let\pgfplots@yticklabel=\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@y
    }
}
\makeatother
```

But I have no idea what all this means. Can somebody help me?

**EDIT: This is the complilable code LaRiFaRi requested.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=16cm, compat=1.12}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=tab]{Exoplanets/test.dat}\datatable
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/flexible yticklabels from table/.code n args={3}{%
        \pgfplotstableread[#3]{#1}\coordinate@table
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumn{#2}\of{\coordinate@table}\to\pgfplots@yticklabels
        \let\pgfplots@yticklabel=\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@y
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title=Fig. 1: Exoplanets data and model prediction, 
    xmode=log, xlabel={Semi-major axis (AU)},
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{PLANET} \as \labelplanet},
    nodes near coords={\labelplanet},
    flexible yticklabels from table={Exoplanets/test.dat}{STAR}{col sep=tab}, ytick=data, y dir=reverse,
]
\addplot+[mark=*, only marks, mark size=0.33, error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit] 
table[x=R,x error plus=RU,x error minus=RL,y=SN,col sep=tab] {Exoplanets/test.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The tab spaces are lost while pasting here. Which one is the planet column?

Comment: Please give us some compilable code! We need to type several lines just to compile this.

Comment: The planet column is the lowercase letter. R, RU, RL are the numbers.